# How to unpack dict with one key-value pair to two variables more elegantly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

Currently, I'm using this:

```
d = {'a': 'xyz'}
k, v = list(*d.items())
```

The starred expression is required here, as omitting it causes the list function/constructor to return a list with a single tuple, which contains the key and value.

However, I was wondering if there were a better way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep nesting:

```
>>> d = {'a': 'xyz'}
>>> ((k,v),) = d.items()
>>> k
'a'
>>> v
'xyz'
```

Or equivalently:

```
>>> (k,v), = d.items()
>>> k
'a'
>>> v
'xyz'
>>>
```

Not sure which I prefer, the last one might be a bit difficult to read if I was glancing at it.

Note, the advantage here is that it is non-destructive and fails if the dict has more than one key-value pair.

Comment: I like that last one :P but I, too, would have to stare down what's happening.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind the dictionary getting altered, this'll do:

```
k, v = d.popitem()
```

Answer (score 5):

Since dict items do not support indexed access, you might resort to the following non-mutating retrieval of the first (and only) item:

```
k, v = next(iter(d.items()))
```

This has the advantage of not only working for dicts of any size, but remaining an `O(1)` operation which other solutions that unpack the items or convert them to a list would not.